# jquery not functioning for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two groups that have a `radio` button. What it does is, when a package above is chosen, the chosen package below should be the same from the above, vice-versa. Example is if I choose "Deluxe" in the first one, the other one should also be "Deluxe". The problem is, when I choose, "Deluxe"  at the top, the other package is still on the previous selection. At first try, everything is working but when you try selecting again, the problem occurs. Also I want to highlight the selected package.
The other part of the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/)

Html

```
<table class="tblPackage">
<thead>
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td width="30%"></td>
            <td width="1%"></td>
            <td width="19%" valign="top">
                <div class="d17_1">
                    <div class="d17_2">ECONOMY</div><span class="s11">$49</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="19%" valign="top">
                <div class="d17_1">
                    <div class="d17_2">DELUXE</div><span class="s11">$79</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="19%" valign="top">
                <div class="d17_1">
                    <div class="d17_2">ULTIMATE</div><span class="s11">$149</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <colgroup>
            <col id="colA"/>
            <col id="colB"/>
            <col id="colC"/>
            <col id="colD"/>
            <col id="colE"/>
        </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                    <td  style="text-align: left;"><h5>Choose Package</h5></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                            <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" checked value="49.00" id="tcbx1" class="css-checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colC')"/>
                            <label for="tcbx1" class="css-label"></label>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                            <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" value="79.00" id="tcbx2" class="css-checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colD')"/>
                            <label for="tcbx2" class="css-label"></label>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                            <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" value="149.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox" onclick="ChangeColColor(this,'colE')"/>
                            <label for="tcbx3" class="css-label"></label>
                        </center>
                    </td>                       
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<table class="tblsubPackage" width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td width="31%"><h5>Choose Package</h5></td>
        <td width="19%" valign="top">
            <div class="d17_1">
                <div class="d17_2">ECONOMY </div><span class="s11">$49</span>
            </div>
            <center>
                <input type="radio" name="radiog_lit" checked value="49.00" id="tscbx1" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="tscbx1" class="css-label"></label>
            </center>
        </td>
        <td width="19%" valign="top">
            <div class="d17_1">
                <div class="d17_2">DELUXE</div><span class="s11">$79</span>
            </div>
            <center>
                <input type="radio" name="radiog_lit" value="79.00" id="tscbx2" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="tscbx2" class="css-label"></label>
            </center>
        </td>
        <td width="19%" valign="top">
            <div class="d17_1">
                <div class="d17_2">ULTIMATE</div><span class="s11">$149</span>
            </div>
                <center>
                    <input type="radio" name="radiog_lit" value="149.00" id="tscbx3" class="css-checkbox" />
                    <label for="tscbx3" class="css-label"></label>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to use `.prop()` to modify the checked property, not `.attr()`. Also, if you're repeating the same logic 6 times in a row, you should think about abstracting that logic into a separate function. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your code by using jQuery's start with selector for radio button having `id`s starting with either `tscbx` or `tcbx` as shown below and get the index of the id to find corresponding radio button.

You need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Also to set background color, you can put `data-col` attribute in radio button and use the same to find `col` and set its background color (though it is not working in JSFiddle).

```
<input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" 
       checked value="49.00" id="tcbx1" 
       class="css-checkbox" data-col="colC"/>
```

jQuery:-

```
$('input[type="radio"][id^="tscbx"]').click(function() {  
    var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('tscbx','');
   $('#tcbx'+index).prop('checked', true);    
});

$('input[type="radio"][id^=tcbx]').click(function() {  
    var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('tcbx','');
    $('#tscbx'+index).prop('checked', true);

    //remove all colgroup background
    $('colgroup col').css('background-color','white');
    //put selected bacground for selected radio
    var colId= $(this).data('col');
    var varColor = "rgba(0,140,203,.2)";
    $('#'+colId).css('background-color',varColor);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/30/)**

Comment: thank you. I tried the highlight thing, and it is not working unless I put my `function ChangeColColor(chkCol,col)` but I'm still not satisfied with it because when I'm changing my answer, it still have a highlight even though there's no check.

Comment: What is `rgba(0,140,203,.2)` this color means, can you try putting color name directly as you put `white`. Use my code only.

Comment: it is a light bluish color with an opacity.

Comment: Oh I got the mistake .. I have put color change code in other radio button click handler, please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/30/) and let me correct it in answer. Also make note that css property is `background-color` and not `backgroundColor`

Comment: Happy to help you :). Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/32/) if you want to set background color when selecting below radio buttons also.

Answer (score 1):

handle it with single click event.

```
$('.tcbx').click(function (event) {
    var test = $(this).data('test');
    $('#'+test).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

just make sure you have a `data` attribute in option which matches with the `id` attribute of sub package or viceversa

```
  <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" checked value="49.00" id="tcbx1" 
       class="css-checkbox tcbx" data-test="tscbx1" />
                      //---^^^^ added a class here
```

and add a class.

I know there are lot of other ways to figure this out, one of which is comparing the index in both tables and doing the needful likewise. But for fast response and since you already have different id for all the checkboxes, i added this function.

This is just a sample you can actaully avoid having different `id` hope you will work on it

Note: you can change `test` to what ever variable you like.

here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/aohsny6y/20/

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery 1.9 or higher you need to user `.prop("checked", true)` instead of `.atrr()`

Fot the Highlighting create a CSS Class and Change it with `.toogleClass`

Comment: He wants to highlight on select and not on hover

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tscbx3').attr('checked','true')
```